# Using mac os host running virtual box with ubuntu not able to forward traffic

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

My host is a mac OS sierra 10.12.4 I am using virtual box running a Ubuntu server 16.04.2 guest. I am trying to set up port forwarding so that I can use the ubuntu guest as a web server and be able to ssh into it. This has worked previously for me using Windows hosts. I set up port forwarding by going into virtual box settings -> network -> advanced -> port forwarding and putting in these configuration settings:

[image: Port forwarding settings]

I am using the ip address for guest by going into ubuntu host and running ifconfig. Here is the output:

[image: if config output]

My localhost ip address is 127.0.0.1 . I know apache is running on guest, but when I go to localhost or 127.0.0.1 in browser I get connection refused. When I try to ssh into the guest by using ip address 127.0.0.1 and port 22 I get connection refused. Anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? 
Host mac firewall is off.

Comment: I just realized you were trying to listen on your host box on ports lower than 1024. Those ports require privilege account, like root. Try adding 8000 to host ports so it will be 8080, 8443 and 8022. After starting the instance, run `netstat -ln | grep 8080` to see that you now have a listener on port 8080 which will be forwarded to guest port 80.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion worked! If you post an answer I'll accept it. is that a Mac thing? In windows I used host port 80

Comment: It's all OS thing. In windows, your account has Administrator privilege, usually via group Administrator Membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All OSes require privilege account to listen on ports lower than 1024.

In Windows it worked because your account is usually an Administrator by virtue of being a member of Administrator group.

By changing the host side ports to higher than 1024, it should work. I suggest adding 8000 to all the host side ports.

You should end up with `8080`, `8443`, and `8022`.